# Drawing line between two JPanels

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, graphics2d

I want to draw lines between two JPanels ; please verify my code as its giving an NULL pointer Exception at 
"g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);"

Code::

```
Draw(JPanel one , JPanel two)
{
    //Draw Line
     Graphics2D g=null;
     Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
     g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
     RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
     g2d.setColor(Color.lightGray);
     2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
     g2d.setColor(Color.black);
     Stroke s = new BasicStroke(4.0f);


    // For getting the points of JPanel ona and two//

     int x1 = one.getX() + one.getWidth() / 2;
     int y1 = one.getY() + one.getHeight() / 2;
     int x2 = one.getX() + one.getWidth() / 2;
     int y2 = two.getY() + two.getHeight() / 2;

    //Drawing line
     g2d.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Because you are **casting** and **storing** `NULL` value to `g2d`.

Look at this code:

```
Graphics2D g=null;
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
```

In the first line, `g` is `NULL`. And it is being cast and assigned to `g2d`. So, `g2d` becomes `NULL` which means it can't be used.

Comment: what to do then ? suggestions ?

Comment: It is highly unrecommended to override `paint` of any component.  I'm also fairly certain that if you did override the `paint` method of the parent container, it would still not work properly. Spent some time with a similar question and run into that problem my self

Comment: @asd, please refer MadProgrammer's answer on how to accurately use Graphics component

Comment: Just a reference for both of you, check out [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details about painting in Swing ;)

Comment: how to include panels ??  JPanel one and JPanel two paint(Graphics,JPanel one,JPanel two) is not working

Comment: @asd, please post any new code in the Question. it is easy to read and follow.

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of options.

The basic premises is, you need some way to paint "over" the top of the current container (and it's children).

You could, override the `paint` method of the parent container, but this HIGHLY unrecommended as it can produce a lot of nasty side-effects.

A better solution would to take advantage of the `JRootPane`'s glass pane

- Check [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) for more details.
- Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804136/connect-jbuttons-visually-via-line/14804252#14804252) for an example

You could also use `JXLayer` (or `JLayer` as it's known in Java 7) to achieve the same results, but I don't have an example readily available